# Ethereum wallet sync stucks only 100 blocks left

Tags: wallets

I have problem with finishing sync of my Ethereum wallet. It stucks 100 blocks before the end, it´s trying to download long chain structure, but it stops every time at some point - on screen it stoped at 683391 of 687160. After restart, it runs again and it stops at some point again.

[image]

I haven´t find same problem in troubleshooting, so I hope this is not repost.

I´ll be very grateful for any advice.

Best regards,

Kuba

Comment: This topic appears often here, you may want to read links to "go-ethereum". Also here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18709/geth-chaindata-copied-syncd-keystore-account-updated-balance-0-heavy-act?noredirect=1#comment20162_18709, and on github:  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14571 - people are working on it, but no clear path to root cause analysis...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the internet time to "time.nist.gov".
Control pannel--> Clock,Language...--> Date and time--> Internet time.
For me it worked (it finish all the block and finally i can see my balance),but after some times is stuck again on the last blocks (180).
I' ve done it yesterday.
And i also run Geth before the ethereum wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the issue as well trying to sync the main net on my laptop. After some research I found this explanation: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16251#issuecomment-371449572

Basically the issue for me was that my MBP has HDD and not SSD: It's apparently no longer possible to sync with the blockchain locally on HDD.

I ended up using the *light* sync mode : `geth --light` and so I was able to sync with the chain and deploy contracts etc.

Hope this can help